# How do I stop eclipse from suspending so often?

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I'm currently trying to write a new program, but for some reason my eclipse is suspending every 30 seconds or so. I think that it has something to do with the new code I've been writing.

I'm using eclipse 21-03, my Wildfly Server is Version 21.0.2 and I'm using openJDK-11.

I already tried giving eclipse more RAM, that didn't help.
You can see a picture of my Taskmanager attached. Eclipse is still using so much RAM although I stopped the server as well as the programm. What do I have to do to suspend the workspace task but not stop eclipse from running?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "suspending"? What are you doing and then what happens?

Comment: I'm trying to open a java class to edit my code. I do that while no other programs are running. Eclipse either takes forever to open the class or crashes because the request took too long.

Comment: @Jana That might be caused by a plugin you have installed. What do you get with Eclipse 2021-06 without additional plugins?

Comment: I installed Eclipse 2021-06 but if i import my projects the same prpblem appears. Is it possible that I'm using the wrong java version? I ran and edited the code in a virtual machine and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

1.5 GB is quite normal for Eclipse. Sadly. RAM hog.

There are two possiblilities why Eclipse is suspending code:

1. You have set breakpoints, that are manual instructions that tell Eclipse to stop in Debugging Mode. They are little blue dots on the line numbers in the code window.
2. Some Exceptions fall all the way through the Stack Trace unhandled. If this happens in Debug Mode, Eclipse will halt where the Exception is thrown and tell you the reason.

Solutions:

1. Improve your code so that the Exceptions do not fall through. Use try-catch
2. Remove breakpoints you set
3. Do not run your app in Debug mode, but in normal run mode. This way the debugger is not attached an will not interrupt "normal" flow.

Example of an exception break in debug mode:

- The popup shows that `x` is null, so accessing x.length() will throw a `NullPointerException` (NPE) that is not caught but crashes through to the `Thread`
- In the bottom right, the Debug View shows where and why execution is halted.

[image: This is what a stop looks like when debugger hit uncaught exception]

Comment: But 1.5 GB isn't normal if no code is running, is it? Eclipse already stops working if i just try to open a simple java class. I still made sure to remove all breakpoints and catch all the exceptions that might come up, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Give us an example screenshot of when Eclipse stops, and what it says in the "Debug View", i.e. the little window with the green bug on it (Menu: Window -> Show View -> Debug). And maybe hover over the marked line, too, and show us some of the debugging details that pop up when hovering over the variables.

Comment: And if code is running, this usually does not really impact Eclipse's resources, as most of the action takes place in the JVM that's started (externally) for running the app.

Comment: One way to find out if its your code or eclipse is to open your project in IntelliJ and VCCode or another IDE of your choice.

Comment: No, 1.5 GB is not normal. The screenshot shows a pretty old Eclipse and in the past, for instance Maven has caused high memory consumption. It might also be caused by an additionally installed plugin.